# how to get an array length from vuex store

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

please i have this store and i'm trying to get the totall length of items
[image]

this is my store

```
const state = {
  products: [],
};

const getters = {
  allProducts: state => state.products,
  totalPercentage(state) {
    const totalProducts = state.products.length;
    console.log(state.products.length)
   return ((totalProducts / 100) * 100).toFixed(2);
  }
};
const mutations = {
  SET_PRODUCTS(state, products) {
    state.products = products;
  }
};
```

when i  console.log(state.products.length) i get undefined

this is my vue component

```
 <p>Total Percentage: {{ totalPercentage }}</p>
<script>
import { mapGetters } from "vuex";
export default {
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(["allProducts", "totalPercentage"])
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$store.dispatch("getProducts");
  }
};
</script>
```

this is error in my console

[image]

please how do i go about this

Answer (score 1):

`products` is object with `products` property that is array, so try with

```
state.products.products.length
```